# image downloading script needs slight modifications

Tags: python

I have just written a small function to download and save some images to my hard disk. Now that some urls redirect and/or contain bad file extensions. I have added some validations, however, they cause the script to stop immediately as they hit a bad url. Now, I would like to modify the script a bit that loop continues discarding any bad urls, eventually breaking the loop as I successfully download an image. (Here I need to download just one image successfully). Can you please take a look at my code and share some tips? Thank you

```
from pattern.web import URL, DOM, plaintext, extension
import requests, re, os, sys, datetime, time, re, random

def download_single_image(query, folder, image_options=None):

download_fault = 0
url_link = None
valid_image_ext_list = ['.png', '.jpg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.tiff', 'jpeg'] # not comprehensive
pic_links = scrape_links(query, image_options) # pic_links contains an array of urls
for url in pic_links:
    url = URL(url)

    print "checking re-direction"

    if url.redirect:
        print "redirected, returning"
        return # if there is a redirect, return

    file_ext = extension(url.page)
    print "checking file extension", file_ext

    if file_ext.lower() not in valid_image_ext_list:
        print "not a valid extension, returning"
        return # return if not valid image extension found

    # Download the image.
    print('Downloading image %s... ' % (pic))
    res = requests.get(pic)
    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as exc:
        print('There was a problem: %s' % (exc))

        print ('Saving image to %s...'% (folder))
        if not os.path.exists(folder + '/' + os.path.basename(pic)):
            imageFile = open(os.path.join(folder, os.path.basename(pic)), mode='wb')
            for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
                imageFile.write(chunk)
                imageFile.close()
                print('pic saved %s' % os.path.basename(pic))

            else:
                print('File already exists!')

                return os.path.basename(pic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`return # return if not valid image extension found`

to this:

`continue # return if not valid image extension found`

**First just aborts the loop, second skips to next step.**

PS.File extensions in the world of Internet mean nothing... I would rather just send `HEAD` request with `CURL` to check if it's image or not (by `content-type` that servers returns).

Comment: Few servers respond to HEAD requests.

Comment: Yeah, well... probably true... Still the answer is there.